# Почему не работает компилятор

Tags: codeblocks

Поставил Code blocks , вставил исходник но он вообще молчит . (сразу говорю пробовал settings - > debugger and compiler -> нажал auto detect) Но все равно не работает , в чем проблема ? 
компилятор MingW  про крайней мере так так написано.(Windows)

Comment: Какая система? Есть ли компилятор в среде для того языка на котором вы пишите?

Comment: автодетект что то нашел или просто нажали и пусть он там сам с интернета качает?